# Limit usage of disk I/O by Docker container, using compose

Tags: docker

I need to deploy few Docker containers on Ubuntu along with limiting their usage of disk I/O. I prefer to do that by using Docker compose-up, but unfortunately, the documentation for version 3 mentions only limiting CPU and memory:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
```

While simply using docker run,I can use options: --device-write-bps, --device-write-iops, --device-read-bps, --device-read-iops.

Comment: There seems to be an issue for this since late 2016 but as far as I can see it is still open: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4056

Answer (score 1):

It seems these options were deliberately removed on Docker 3.0 for compatibility with swarm.

See https://forums.docker.com/t/blkio-config-does-not-exist-in-v3-0-or-later/94373.

To quote user meyay:

> If you have a single node, then docker-compose and v2.4 is still the way to go and way more powerful then swarm will ever be. Swarm lacks privileged mode, capabilities, devices and other “low level” features.
>
> If you require multi node cluster container deployments and still need full control of everything, a move to Kubernetes is inevitable.

Comment: I really start to hate docker v3 more and more